# how to pass route id to controller method using angularJs?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

here is code of view1.html :-

```
<a href="/questions/{{categoty.QuestionCategoryId}}">
```

Here is code of App.js :-

```
.when('/questions/:id', { templateUrl: 'Templates/QuestionsPage.html',  controller: 'SmartLearnerController' })
```

here i m getting id parameter while click on href.

here is my .net controller code where i want to pass above id :-

```
public JsonResult GetQuestionList(int id)
    {
        var data = db.GetAllQuestions().Where(a => a.QuestionID == id).ToList();
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now question is how to pass id from App.js to ASP.net controller using service or function of angularJs ?

Answer (score 3):

Inject `$routeParams` in your controller as dependency and use `$routeParams.id`

Comment: @Thanks for your reply, Can you please explain how to use controller as dependency ?

Comment: $routeParams is dependency of controller (SmartLearnerController in your case). inject $routeParams as you inject other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you want build **href** of *< a >* tag from controller you need use **ng-href** instead href in *< a >* tag. Check [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)